# How do you use grep with man command?

Tags: linux, grep, man

I saw a guy how used this command `man ssh grep -e "version number"` and then got the option printed out for him. But when I do the same command, I get the same result as man ssh. So can the video be outdated and the command looks different now, or did he use some kind of magic?

Comment: You missed putting a `|` between ssh and grep. You need to pipe the output of one command to the input of the next.

Comment: You also have the ability to search within the man page by using `/` such as `/version number`.  You can then use `n` to advance to the next matching pattern or `shift+n` to return to the previous.

Comment: See also `LESS='+/version number' man ssh` (assuming `less` is the default man pager)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that the video showed:

```bsh
man ssh | grep -e "version number"
```

instead, and the pipe symbol (`|`) was visually obscured or missed.